# "else cannot start a statement" issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried making a program where every few seconds a random letter dropped. I noticed that the "correct" one dropped to rarely. I made a `int correctLetterDrop = Random.Range(0,100)` and wanted to artificially increase the chance. The rest of the code handles everything, i just need to assign the correct sprite to check against.

This gives me an error at the .correctSprite; saying "else cannot start a statement". I expect it to just check if the Random.Range returned 7 or less (for a 7% chance) and if it did to set the correct one, and otherwise just set a random one.

```
 if(correctLetterDrop <= 7){
             Clone.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = correctLetterScript.correctSprite;

             else{
             
                 Clone.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Letters[Letter];
             }
        }
```

Comment: You need `}` before `else` to terminate the `if` block.

Comment: Remove all '{' and '}' and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the first if condition closure `}`:

```
if(correctLetterDrop <= 7) {
    Clone.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = correctLetterScript.correctSprite;
}else{
    Clone.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Letters[Letter];
}
```

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo) ;)